# Recover unallocated partition next to EFI System Partition (WIndows 10)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I am trying to extend my boot partition with unallocated space. However, the space is after the EFI System partition so I don't have the option to extend. It looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to extend to the C drive. How would I go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't do this without getting rid of the EFI and recreating it.  This is not a procedure I suggest you do, if you don't already know how to do it, and know how to solve the numerous potential problems caused by doing so.  I suggest you live with the current partition structure.  If you are willing to delete your partitions, removing all partitions, and allowing the Windows installation to create the partitions is a straight forward way to acomplish what you want.

Comment: If I installed another OS (Ubuntu 16) in the unallocated space, will it cause problems?

Comment: Of course not.  You should make appropriate backups incase something does go wrong though.

Comment: I think my best option is to install another OS then, as I wanted to anyways, instead of deleting all the partitions. Thank you for the help!